# Copy and Move Script

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a Lambda script for S3 that works like this:  As soon as I upload an image into my s3 bucket, it copies it and moves it into a subfolder.  Is there a way to do this?

Ideally I'd like to get it to work with Kraken as well so that I can make multiple copies of the image in different sizes that puts each sized image into a respective folder, but I figure I can build to that if I can get the copy and move functionality down first.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [Handling Amazon S3 Events Using the AWS Lambda Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-amazons3-events.html) walkthrough that shows how to trigger Amazon Lambda when objects are added to Amazon S3. This example resizes images and places them in a different bucket.

Once you have it working, you could then modify the code for your particular use-case.